# Erratic declaration behavior: Rational.h:25: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘&’ token

Tags: c++

so, I have been having issues in this header file overloading the stream insertion operator. I receive the error message in the title if I use the code as is. But when I put the declaration in the main file, it works fine.

Rational.h

```
#ifndef RATIONAL_H
#define RATIONAL_H

using namespace std;
class Rational{
private:
    int numerator;
    unsigned int denominator;
    bool isNegative;

public:
    Rational();
    Rational(int);
    Rational(int, int);

    bool operator==(const Rational&);
    Rational& operator++(int);          //Unused int
    Rational operator-(const Rational&);
    Rational operator+(const Rational&);
    Rational operator*(const Rational&);
    Rational operator/(const Rational&);
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream&, Rational&); //Erroneous code


#endif
```

The other two files, 1.c and Rational.c if needed:

```
#include "Rational.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

Rational::Rational(){
numerator   = 0;
denominator = 1;
}

Rational::Rational(int num){
numerator   = num;
denominator = 1;     
}

Rational::Rational(int num, int den){
//Determine negativity
if(num < 0 xor den < 0){    //If negative
    if(num > 0){
        num *= -1;
    }
}

numerator   = num;
denominator = abs(den);  
}

bool Rational::operator==(const Rational& rhs){
return (numerator/(double)denominator == rhs.numerator/(double)(rhs.denominator));
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Rational& input){
os << "Moo";
return os;
}
/*
private:
    int  numerator;
    unsigned int  denominator;
    bool isNegative;

public:
    Rational(int, int);

    bool operator==(const Rational&);
    Rational& operator++(int);          //Unused int
    Rational operator-(const Rational&);
    Rational operator+(const Rational&);
    Rational operator*(const Rational&);
    Rational operator/(const Rational&);
*/
```

1.c

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Rational.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){
Rational test = Rational(2);

cout << test << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include `iostream` in your `Rational.h`

**//Rational.h**

```
#include <iostream>
```

When you put the overload declaration in `1.c`, `iostream` is included before `Rational.h` and hence compiler knows the type `ostream` and there is no error.

However, `Rational.h` does not include `iostream` so in that case compiler does not know the type `ostream` and hence the error.

Comment: Oh how helpful those diagnostics are.